# How to display CHOICES in Django ModelForm

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-model-field, limit-choices-to

- I have a policy_category model with 16 categories.
- I have a Response model to record survey answers. The model includes a field to record the respondent's 1-5 rating for each of the policy categories. (policy_1_rank..policy_16_rank, etc.)

I can't figure out how to display the CHOICES I created for each field:

> Form Template

```
 <div><b>How important are each of the following issues or policy areas to you, when you're selecting a candidate for president?</b></div>
<div><br></div>
<ul><div>{{ policy_category.object(pk=1) }}</div></ul>
# show POLICY_1_CHOICES below:
<div>{{ form.policy_1_rank }}</div>

<div><br></div>
<ul><div>{{ policy_category.object(pk=2) }}</div></ul>
# show POLICY_2_CHOICES below:
<div>{{ form.policy_2_rank }}</div>
...
```

> Responses Model:

```
# Temp Survey Response
class Temporaryresponse(models.Model):
    # Healthcare
    POLICY_1_CHOICES = [
    (1, '1: Extremely supportive of a healthcare system with ONLY private insurance'),
    (2, '2: Somewhat supportive of a healthcare system with ONLY private insurance'),
    (3, '3: Somewhat supportive of a healthcare system with BOTH private insurance and a public insurance option'),
    (4, '4: Extremely supportive of a healthcare system with BOTH private insurance and a public insurance option'),
    (5, '5: Somewhat supportive of a healthcare system with ONLY public insurance (commonly referred to as "universal healthcare")'),
    (6, '6: Extremely supportive of a healthcare system with ONLY public insurance (commonly referred to as "universal healthcare")'),
]
...
# Healthcare
    policy_1_rank = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0, choices=POLICY_1_CHOICES)
```

> Forms.py

```
class NextresponseForm(ModelForm):
    policy_1_rank = forms.IntegerField()
    policy_2_rank = forms.IntegerField()
...

class Meta:
        model = Temporaryresponse
        fields = ['policy_1_rank', 'policy_2_rank',...]
```

***EDIT: Maybe the answer below isn't working because there is a problem with my view. I'm trying to navigate from a first form page "tr.html", save the data, and send the pk of the response to "nr.html" for a second part of the survey. This is working. But is my view of "nr.html" incorrect?***

> views.py

```
# Create temporary response view - this saves and goes to nr perfectly. pk produced from saving the response shows in nr link in web browser (myapp/nr/pk# shows here perfectly.)
def tr(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TemporaryresponseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            tempresponse = form.save()
            tempresponse.save()
            return redirect('nr', pk=tempresponse.pk)
    else:
        form = TemporaryresponseForm()
    return render(request, 'politicalexperimentpollapp/tr.html', {'form': form})


def nr(request, pk):
    tempresponse = get_object_or_404(Temporaryresponse, pk=pk)
    instance = Temporaryresponse.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NextresponseForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            nextresponse = form.save()
            nextresponse.save()
            return redirect('fr', pk=nextresponse.pk)
    else:
        form = NextresponseForm(instance=instance)
    return render(request, 'politicalexperimentpollapp/nr.html', {'tempresponse': tempresponse}, {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override your form's fields in `__init__` to include a [`forms.ChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield):

```
class NextresponseForm(ModelForm):  
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['policy_1_rank'] = forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=self._meta.model.POLICY_1_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
            model = Temporaryresponse
            fields = ['policy_1_rank', 'policy_2_rank',...]
```

### Update

The easiest way to render a form object in django is to pass it as context in your view:

```
def some_view(request):
    form = NextresponseForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', context)
```

Then you can access the form by calling `form.as_ul` in your template:

```
<ul>
{{ form.as_ul }}
</ul>
```

### Update 2

The last line in your views is incorrect:

```
return render(request, 'politicalexperimentpollapp/nr.html', {'tempresponse': tempresponse}, {'form': form})
```

Instead this should be:

```
return render(request, 'politicalexperimentpollapp/nr.html', {'tempresponse': tempresponse, 'form': form})
```

`context` is a *dictionary*.  If you need to pass multiple items to your template, you need to include multiple keys in your context dictionary, not multiple arguments.

Lastly, I'd recommend *always* initializing forms with `request.POST or None`, to avoid invalidating your form:

```
    form = TemporaryresponseForm(request.POST or None)
```

This a textbook answer to a commonly asked question *"Why is `form.is_valid()` always invalid?"*.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I do this I get this error: 'NextresponseForm' object has no attribute 'model'.

Comment: @jm2288 Sorry, you tried the version before I updated.  You can't access `self.model`, so you'll have to use the model directly, or use `self._meta.model`.

Comment: Thanks, these two ways don't display any choices in the form. Should I change how I reference it in the html? Right now I'm using
<div>{{ form.policy_1_rank }}</div>

Comment: @jm2288 I added an update to explain the preferred way to render a form.  Also **note** that I removed `widget` from `self.fields['policy_1_rank']` (see my update), because `ChoiceField` is a form field object, and not a widget.

Comment: Thanks. Since it still isn't working I'm thinking maybe the issue is actually my views.py. I edited my question above. Thank you so much for all of your help.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. The only other problem I had above is displaying policy_area(pk=1) in my form html. Would you happen to know how to do this?

Comment: @jm2288 I'm not sure what that is, also it seems a bit out of scope for this question.  If you need more help, you should ask a new question and I can assist you further.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks so much. I will remove that from the question above and put in a new question. Thanks!